# linguistics competitions?

Tags: computational-linguistics

Looking for *Linguistics Competitions* suitable for MSc or PhD students in Computational Linguistics.  I don't see anything current on [Kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/competitions), and I am looking into [TREC](https://trec.nist.gov/faq.html).
**added:** recurring preferred (thank you, @tripleee).

I'm just a student myself, so I would welcome any pointers about where to look that experienced Linguists can suggest.

---

I thought about whether this is an *answerable* question and it seems that community resources, like competitions, *may* have concrete answers (vs "only opinions").  So I'm tentatively raising the question.  And I am totally open to being corrected and will un-ask if this won't be helpful to others (or is otherwise ill-suited for the stackexchange Linguistics forum).

Comment: SQuAD, the Winograd Schema Challenge, and the WMT workshops for each problem area, eg http://www.statmt.org/wmt18/quality-estimation-task.html.

Comment: Many competitions are one-off, which means answers will inherently be struggling with out of date information. Maybe ask specifically for recurring competitions ...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is one that I know of: Low Resource Languages for Emergent Incidents (LORELEI)

[Here is the link](https://www.nist.gov/itl/iad/mig/lorehlt-evaluations) (also a NIST competition)

Comment: Thank you, marked as accepted.  I posted an email excerpt from NIST as well.

Answer (score 1):

NIST was kind enough to relay this by email (April 2018):

re Text Retrieval Conference (TREC):

> The [**call for participation in TREC 2018**](https://trec.nist.gov/pubs/call2018.html) is still active, so
>   you can sign up to participate this year is you would like.  You can
>   learn more about the types of tasks the tracks have focused on in
>   previous years from the Overview papers in the Proceedings.  The
>   proceedings are in the Publications section of the TREC web site
>   [**https://trec.nist.gov/**](https://trec.nist.gov/)
>
> TREC's focus is on search, and while there is definitely room for
>   linguistic approaches to search, that is not the most frequent
>   approach.  Our group at NIST has a sibling project to TREC called the
>   [**Text Analysis Conference (TAC)**](https://tac.nist.gov/) that focuses specifically on
>   natural language processing tasks.  The TAC link currently points to
>   TAC 2017, but I expect it will be updated for TAC 2018 very soon.
>
> You might also be interested in evaluations run by the [**NIST
>   Multimodal Information Group**](https://www.nist.gov/itl/iad/mig).